# Getting TypeError when wrapping input().split() in int()

Tags: python-3.x

So I just wanted to know the reason and cause of error I am getting in order to get a better understanding of python.

Here is what I have tried.

**Code snippet #1**

```
x,y=int(input()),int(input())
print(x,y)
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```

So I get the output -

```
4
6
4 6
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

I am fine with the output, but what bugs me is why I can't use it in the manner like -

**Code snippet #2**

```
x,y= int(input().split('-'))
print(x,y)
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```

So here, on wrapping *input().split()* inside int(), it throws an error as :

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'list'

**My Doubt**

I just want to know why I cannot wrap int() inside input().split() ? Is there an alternate way to do it? Or if it's not allowed please explain why.

Comment: Because split returns a list. You can't cast list to int. You should use list comprehension or `map` to make it work.

Comment: @dyukha you are correct. I just came across the concept of map and found what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so if you want to take multiple inputs in a single line and also convert it into desired data type, you can use map() to achieve it.

**Code snippet #3**

```
x,y,z=map(int,input().strip().split())
print(x,y,z)
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
print(type(z))
```

So your output will look like this -

```
2 3 4
2 3 4
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

And as @dyukha pointed out correctly the reason you cannot wrap input().split() inside int() is because split() returns a list and we cannot cast list to int data type.

Answer (score 2):

From [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> str.split() returns a **list** of the words in str

You can not turn a `list` to a `int`

You can try this way:

```
(x, y) = (int(x) for x in input().split('-'))
print(x, y)
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```

Comment: Your solution is also acceptable and an alternate way to get the job done.Appreciate your help.